# How to edit information in edit mode via object mode

Tags: python, blender

I have found this piece of code which select face with given index in object mode:
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001'].data.polygons[0].select

I want to do some other manipulations in object mode like select_similar, select_all(action'INVERT') and delete(type='ONLY_FACE').

I tryed to find information about .data.polygons[0].select in oficial api, but did not get any sucsess.

I want to do this in object mode, without entering edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.polygons[0].select` is a boolean property of a face, which is a [MeshPolygon](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html) object. It stores a true or false value and there isn't much else you can learn about it.

The select similar operator simply loops through the faces and sets select to true if it matches a criteria.

```
import bpy

obj_data = bpy.context.object.data

for f in obj_data.polygons:
    if f.area < 0.1:
        f.select = True
    else:
        f.select = False
```

to invert the selection

```
for f in obj_data.polygons:
    f.select = not f.select
```

Note that this will only work in object mode as edit mode uses bmesh and will overwrite any changes on exiting edit mode. You will find [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html) is a better option for editing mesh data and you don't have to put the object into edit mode to use it.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj_data = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj_data)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bad_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.calc_area() < 0.1]

bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=bad_faces, context=5)

bm.to_mesh(obj_data)
bm.free()
obj_data.update()
```

If the obect is in edit mode you would use [`from_edit_mesh`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#bmesh.from_edit_mesh) and `update_edit_mesh`. You can find some info on the context paramater for `bmesh.ops.delete()` [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1542/935).

Comment: Thank you very much! This really helps. Did not think about bmesh, need to study it :) but I dont understand how to do render of edited mesh. I am using animate nodes with python script and if I will do render I get 'Context' object has no attribute 'object'

Comment: Is that a script node in the animation nodes tree? Do you have `Context` or `context` - all lowercase? Ask another question with the failing script. You will find [blender.stackexchange.com](https://blender.stackexchange.com) more helpful for blender specific scripting.